# Connect to an Azure hosted ElasticSearch endpoint through a SSL offloading Application Gateway

Tags: .net, azure, elasticsearch, nest, azure-marketplace

I have used the template [Elasticsearch Azure Marketplace](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace) to deploy an ElasticSearch cluster in Azure.

I configured it with SSL/TLS for communication with Elasticsearch via the HTTP layer through Application Gateway and everything works fine, I can log in to Kibana and see the status of my cluster nodes.

The problem is I can't connect to ElasticSearch using NEST.NET through the Azure Application Gateway from a client, it requires the certificate and password I provided when submitting the template but when I set it I get **"Unable to read data from the transport connection"** and **"The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."** when I send a request.

Here's the code I use from my client to connect to ElasticSearch:

```
    public IElasticClient Client { get; }

    public ElasticService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(configuration["Elastic:Endpoint"]))
            .DefaultIndex("impression");
        settings.ClientCertificate(new X509Certificate2(@"C:\git\server.p12", "PASSWORD", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable));
        Client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate in this case isn't used for certificate authentication to Elasticsearch, as the `ClientCertificate` method is used for, but is used for Transport Layer Security (TLS).

A TLS certificate can be set with `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(configuration["Elastic:Endpoint"]));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
    .BasicAuthentication("elastic", "<password>")
    .ServerCertificateValidationCallback(
        CertificateValidations.AuthorityPartOfChain(
            new X509Certificate2(@"C:\git\server.p12", "PASSWORD"))
    );

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Depending on how the certificate passed to Application Gateway has been generated, `CertificateValidations` offers `AuthorityPartOfChain` and `AuthorityIsRoot`, depending on if the certificate with which the client configured is part of the chain, or is the root certificate, respectively.

Comment: I think it's on the right path but it still throw the same error. I have set the URI to https://buypass-elastic.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:9200/, I am sure of my two passwords and the certificate is valid. I don't understand what is going on. I have tested both AuthorityPartOfChain and AuthorityIsRoot

Comment: If you hit Application Gateway public IP directly and enter the `elastic` basic auth details - do you get a `200 OK` response?

Comment: Just to precise, I am using a self signed certificate

Comment: what about from the browser (accepting any invalid certificate warnings)?

Comment: I get the same thing in Chrome. It seems the server closes it immediately

Comment: On an other port than 9200, it keeps refreshing and leads to a TimeOut instead

Comment: It sounds to me like Application Gateway _may_ not be healthy. What does Azure portal report for the health probe for Application Gateway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178785/discussion-between-russ-cam-and-ben).

Comment: Thanks to @Russ Cam I managed to get this working, I have misreading the docs. Works perfectly fine using an External load balancer.